# Non Linear Equation Solve

Tags: equation-solving

[image]

```
a = 1/Pi ((t/2 - 1)*ArcCos[1 - 2/t] + (-1 + 4/(3 t) - 4/(3 t^2)) Sqrt[t - 1]);
Solve[-0.5 - a == 0, t]
```

There is a way to solve this non linear equation??
Thanx

Comment: Try using ‘NSolve[] instead of ‘Solve[]

Comment: Expect no more effort from an answer than what you put into the question.

Comment: Plotting `a` against `t` will help you determine the number of solutions.

Comment: If you put the equation in the post  in a form that I can copy and paste then I will have a look. I don't want to have to type it up myself.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Achille! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4):

We are looking for the value of `t` that makes the expression `-1/2 - a == 0`. As suggested by JimB plotting the function can be useful. Thus

```
Plot[-(1/2) - a, {t, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This has no values for `t < 1` suggesting that the equation is complex. Mathematica only plots an expression when there are real values. To see if the expression is complex we can plot its real and imaginary parts.

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[-(1/2) - a]], {t, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-2, 10}}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"Re", "Im"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This plot confirms that the expression is complex for values less than 1 and real for values greater than 1.

You want to see where the expression is zero so examining the regions around `t == 1` gives

```
   Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[-(1/2) - a]], {t, 0.5, 1.5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1.5}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"Re", "Im"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Further if we put in the value `t = 1` into the expression we get

```
-(1/2) - a /. t -> 1
```

> 0

So it looks like you solution is `t = 1` as also shown by Nasser.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

Try on the real domain

```
  ClearAll[t]
  a = 1/Pi ((t/2 - 1)*ArcCos[1 - 2/t] + (-1 + 4/(3 t) - 4/(3 t^2)) Sqrt[t - 1]);

  Solve[-1/2 - a == 0, t, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. changed your input from `-0.5` to `-1/2`. It is always best to use exact input when using `Solve`

Comment: really thanx for all your suggestion...
My problem is to find the solution of the Non linear equation for a continuos range of number starting from -0.5, to 0 (is a data set of experimental point)

my question is to find a possibile method to solve the equation for all the variable i need it...